# How to construct the Lie group homomorphism $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ via the Lie algebra isomorphism $\Lambda:{\frak su}(2)\to{\frak so}(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

The Lie algebra of $ \mathfrak{so(3)} $ and $ \mathfrak{su(2)} $ are respectively

$$ [L_i,L_j] = i\epsilon_{ij}^{\;\;k}L_k $$
$$ [\frac{\sigma_i}{2},\frac{\sigma_j}{2}] = i\epsilon_{ij}^{\;\;k}\frac{\sigma_k}{2} $$

And of course, there is an isomorphism between these two algebras, 
$$ \Lambda : \mathfrak{su(2)} \rightarrow \mathfrak{so(3)} $$ 
such that $ \Lambda(\sigma_i/2) =L_i  $

Now is it possible, **using $\Lambda$**, to construct a group homomorphism between $SU(2)$  and $SO(3)$?

I was checking up on [Lie group homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_homomorphism), and in Wikipedia, there is a beautiful image
[image]

In this image's language, how are $\phi$ and $\phi_*$ related to each other (just like the algebra and group elements are).

**Note** : I know there is a one-to-two homomorphism between these two groups which can be directly found using the group elements. I am not looking for this.

**EDIT 1** : In $ SL(2,\mathbb{R}) $ the generators, say $X_1,X_2,X_3$, they obey the following commutation rules :

$$ [X_1,X_2] = 2X_2 $$
$$ [X_1,X_3] = -2X_3 $$
$$ [X_2,X_3] = X_1 $$

And in the case of $ SO(3) $ with a different basis, $ L_{\pm} = L_1 \pm i L_2 $ and $ L_z = L_3  $ with the commutators being,

$$ [L_z,L_{\pm}]= \pm L_{\pm} $$
$$ [L_+,L_-]= 2 L_z $$

This algebra is very similar to the algebra of the previous one, so why is that we can't define a map ?

**EDIT 2**:

Can the group homomorphism between these two groups be written like this (Something like what I expected) :
$$ R = \exp(\sum_k i t_k L_k) = \exp\left(\sum_k i t_k \frac{\sigma_k}{2}\right) = \exp\left(\sum_k i t_k \frac{1}{2}ln(U_k)\right) $$

Now this seems like the map $\phi$,

$$ R = \phi(U) = \exp\bigg(\sum_k i t_k \frac{1}{2}ln(U_k)\bigg) $$

Comment: In this language, $\phi_\star$ is essentially the differential of $\phi$ (at identity), sometimes also called the pushforward (this is what the star in the index means). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential) This question is probably more appropriate at math.SE.

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): Note that the two generators $L_{\pm}$ do _not_ belong to the Lie algebra $so(3)$. Rather they belong to the complexification $so(3,\mathbb{C})$. Note that the complexifications of the real Lie algebras $su(2)\cong so(3)$ and $sl(2,\mathbb{R})\cong so(2,1)$ are all the same, namely $sl(2,\mathbb{C})\cong so(3,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @Qmechanic : Oh thanks a lot, so a these two things have a similarity ?

Comment: @Qmechanic : So is there also a general rule that, the groups with real/complex parameters have their corresponding Lie Algebra LVS defined over a real/complex field respectively ?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First notice that the generators are $-i\sigma_k/2$ and $-iL_k$, since the groups are **real** Lie groups and thus the structure tensor must be **real**.

The answer to your question is positive. In principle it is enough to take the  exponential of the Lie algebra isomorphism and a surjective Lie group homomorphism arises this way
  $\phi : SU(2)\to SO(3)$: $$\phi\left(\exp\left\{-\sum_k t^k i\sigma_k/2\right\}\right) =\exp\left\{-\sum_k t^k iL_k\right\}\:.$$
The point is that one should be sure that the argument in the left-hand side covers the whole group. For the considered case, this is true because $SU(2)$ is compact.

If you instead consider no compact Lie groups, like $SL(2,\mathbb C)$, the exponential does not cover the group. However it is possible to prove that products of exponential do. In that case a product of two exponentials is sufficient, in practice decomposing an element of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ by means of the polar decomposition, mathematically speaking, or as a (unique) product of a rotation and a boost physically speaking.

Comment: Thanks !! But I wish to know what will be the functional form of this $\phi$. I am pretty new to this subject, can you please be more explicit on that part ?

Comment: Well, everything is already explicit in my answer concerning $\phi$. An element of $SU(2)$ can always written down as an exponential as I wrote (that exponential can be computed and the formula can be found in every book on QM). The fundamental point is that the element is completely fixed by the coefficients $t_k$. These coefficients appear in the right hand side determining the rotation (again written in terms of an exponential) associated with the element of $SU(2)$ in the left hand side.

Comment: @V.Morreti : Thanks !! Since you have pointed about SL(2,R). I also checked that there is an isomorphism between the algebras sl(2,R) and so(3). Therefore, I am guessing there is a similar map for these groups. In that case what is the problem you're trying to address ?

Comment: No, the isomorphism is between sl(2,R) and o(3,1). There is a similar map, but now every element of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ has to be decomposed as a product of two exponentials (using the polar decomposition procedure) and, correspondingly, a product of exponentials appears in the right-hand side corresponding to the standard decomposition of an element of $O(3,1)$ as a product of a $SO(3)$ rotation  and a pure Lorentz transformation.

Comment: @V.Morreti : But sl(2,R) has only 3 generators and o(3,1) has 6. I think you're trying to talk about sl(2,C) and o(3,1).

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I was thinking of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ but I always wrote $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ (the conformal group). The point is that I am presently dealing with the latter and my fingers are more quick than my brain!

Comment: OK :) But then there seems to be an isomorphism between sl(2,R) and so(3) itself which I observed a couple of days ago.

Comment: No, there is no such an isomorphism. SL(2,R) is not compact whereas SO(3) is compact. This implies that no isomorphism of groups or  Lie algebras may exist.

Comment: It would extremely delightful if you could see the EDIT part of this question and explain why we can't construct such a map, Thanks :)

Comment: Well, the answer is simple: You are not allowed to consider this linear combination $L_1 \pm iL_2$ if $L_1,L_2 \in so(3)$. This is because you are dealing with a **real** Lie algebra, so only real linear combinations are possible. If $L_1,L_2 \in so(3)$ then $L_1 \pm iL_2 \not \in so(3)$.

Comment: Obviously the same obstruction arises if, in your notation, $iL_k$ are the generators of $so(3)$.

Comment: One more question (am sorry for the trouble), is the EDIT 2 (that I just added) part in the question appropriate in addressing the group mapping !!

Comment: Yes. tt is enough to define $U_k = e^{\sigma_k}$...

Comment: But I think the Group Homomorphism is two-to-one $ R_{ik} = \frac{1}{2}Tr(U\sigma_i U^{\dagger}\sigma_k) $. How do we justify both these maps ?

Comment: It is the first time I see it. If you are sure that your map $SU(2) \ni U \mapsto R\in SO(3)$ preserves the composition of matrices and that its differential sends $i\sigma_k/2$ to $iL_k$, as it is continuous, it must coincide to the map I wrote using exponentials, since there is exactly one Lie group homomorphism which extends a Lie algebra homomorphism. Also the  expression I provided for the covering homomorphism is two-one. This is because, for instance, $e^{i (t_3 +2\pi) L_3} = e^{i t_3 L_3}$ but $e^{i(t_3 + 2\pi) \sigma_3/2}= - e^{it_3 \sigma_3/2}$.

Answer (score 5):

So I take it you are clearly aware that the [big A Adjoint representation](http://www.wetsavannaanimals.net/wordpress/the-lie-bracket-and-the-little-adjoint-representation/) is the homomorphism you're after in this case, so you're seeking a more general method.

Also, I'm assuming you know that the homomorphism of Lie algebras can only lift to a group homomorphism if the homomorphism's domain is simply connected, in which case there is a unique group homomorphism with the given algebra homomorphism as [its Lie map](http://www.wetsavannaanimals.net/wordpress/the-lie-bracket-and-the-little-adjoint-representation/#InducedLieAlgebraHomomorphismTheorem). In this case, we're in the clear because $SU(2)$ is simply connected. Page 73 through 76 of:

[Anthony Knapp, "Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=U573NrppkA8C&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=Lifting+Lie+group+homomorphism&source=bl&ots=7B5iHjNKNK&sig=VFBR99ReoAkVmHAhaLiEzpTQG3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G2Q6U6vqCMrGkgXX_IHwBA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Lifting%20Lie%20group%20homomorphism&f=false)

can then help you. Knapp gives you two methods of systematically constructing the simply connected Lie group: the first leaves you with differential equations for the left / right invariant vector fields, the second I believe is the same as [V. Moretti's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106108/26076).

A final "method" is to used Ado's theorem, which assures us that we can always realise a Lie algebra as a matrix Lie algebra; there is even an explicit software algorithm for this:

[W. A. De Graaf, "Constructing Faithful Matrix Representations of Lie Algebras"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2802124_Constructing_Faithful_Matrix_Representations_of_Lie_Algebras?ev=prf_pub)

but if you can understand this algorithm, you are doing better than I (this paper has so far defeated me). Once you have a matrix algebra, you can used the matrix exponential to construct a neighbourhood of the identity, indeed the whole group if the latter is compact; as in [V. Moretti's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106108/26076) the Lie algebra does not exponentiate to the whole group for noncompact groups (as far as I am aware, the problem of exactly what in a noncompact Lie group can be realised as an exponential of a Lie algebra element is to some extent still an open problem).

So, once you have the Lie group, you can in principle construct the universal cover with homotopy classes and carve out the discrete centre $\mathcal{Z}_d$ of the universal cover. Your original group will have as its fundamental group the quotient group of $\mathcal{Z}_d$ and one of its (normal) subgroups.

Comment: De Graaf is a colleague of mine! Some doors next to mine.

Comment: @V.Moretti Tell him I still tackle his paper from time to time but still leave off badly bruised! No slight intended on his technical writing abilities: an actual implementation of an Ado theorem algorithm is not an easy thing to convey, I'm likely not the sharpest audience and he's (de Graaf) has certainly done some very beautiful work.

Comment: OK, I will tell him all that you wrote. Bye

Comment: the links to your notes appear to be dead, and now redirects to some *very* sketchy/scummy website