# Subtlety in the proof of 2-to-1 homomorphism between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, topology

In physics, it's common to use the relations $$\textbf{r}^\prime=\mathscr{R}\textbf{r};~~\text{and}~~\textbf{r}^\prime\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}
=\mathscr{U}(\textbf{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}) \mathscr{U}^{\dagger}\tag{1}$$ to establish a two-to-one homomorphism between ${\rm SU(2)}$ and ${\rm SO(3)}$ where $\textbf{r}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathscr{R}\in {\rm SO(3)}$, $\mathscr{U}\in {\rm SU(2)}$ and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ are three Pauli matrices. Both the relations of Eq.(1) represent rotation of coordinates in real three-dimensional space because both of them satisfy $|\textbf{r}^\prime|^2=|\textbf{r}|^2$. It's easy to see from (1) that corresponding to every $3\times 3$ matrix $\mathscr{R}\in {\rm SO(3)}$ there exist **two** $2\times 2$ matrices $\pm \mathscr{U}\in {\rm SU(2)}$ that represent the same rotation.

**Question** Note that the above proof of 2-to-1 homomorphism is based on fundamental representations of $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$. But for any odd-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$, if $\mathscr{U}$ has determinant $+1$, $-\mathscr{U}$ is not a representation of $SU(2)$ since it has determinant $-1$. Hence, if $\mathscr{U}$ is a member of an odd-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$. $\mathscr{U}$ is not. *Does it mean that 2-to-1 homomorphism between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ is not true in general?*

Comment: The homomorphism is defined for groups irrespective of the representations, and $SU(2)$ by definition is a group of 2x2 matrices, so your question is irrelevant for the proof.

Comment: A Special Unitary operator $\:U \in SU(2)\:$  is represented by a  $\:2 \times 2\:$  complex matrix having the general form$$
U  =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha  & \beta  \\
  -\beta^* & \alpha^*
  \end{bmatrix}
 \qquad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C} \qquad \det(U)=\alpha \alpha^* +\beta\beta^* =\left\|\alpha\right\|^2 + \left\|\beta\right\|^2=1  
\tag{01}
$$ ....3-dimensional representation of SU(2).... ???

Comment: @Frobenius Consider the spin-1 representation. It's 3-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the  spin-1 representation has nothing to do with the (matrix) representation of the special unitary operators $\:U \in SU(2)$. I don't think you are confused. Something else is in your mind but may be you don't ask the right question.

Comment: "_But the spin-1 representation has nothing to do with the (matrix) representation of the special unitary operators $U\in SU(2).$_" This is wrong. The two-dimensional representation is only the fundamental representation. There are higher dimensional representations of SU(2) as well. In fact, the irreducible representations of SU(2) are $(2j+1)$ dimensional where $j$ is either an integer or a half-integer. What is the problem? Are you saying SU(2) has only @2\times 2$ matrix representation? If yes, that's wrong. @Frobenius

Comment: @downvoter Can the downvoter please care to comment what's wrong with the question.

Comment: @Peter Kravchuk gave you the answer. Representations of groups are one thing, groups themselves (and group elements in particular) are another. You are mixing the two.

Comment: @SRS  You're right. I apologize, may be I was confused not understanding your question from the beginning. By the way, I am against those users who down vote questions or answers without a comment to explain  why.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: The status of the group isomorphism$^1$ $SO(3)\cong SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and OP's eq. (1) are not jeopardize by the existence of non-faithful $SU(2)$ representations, cf. above comments by Peter Kravchuk and DanielC.

In more details:

1. Let $\rho$ denote the $n$-dimensional irreducible Lie group representation $\rho: SU(2)\to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, and (with a slight misuse of notation) let $\rho$ also denote the corresponding $n$-dimensional irreducible Lie algebra representation $\rho: su(2)\to gl(n,\mathbb{C})$.
2. Then
   $$\rho(\pm {\bf 1}_{2\times 2})~=~(\pm 1)^{n+1}{\bf 1}_{n\times n},$$
   and
   $$ {\rm ker}(\rho)~:=~ \rho^{-1}(\{{\bf 1}_{n\times n}\})~=~\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
   \{{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\} & \text{for }   n \geq 2\text{ even}, \cr
   \{\pm{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\} & \text{for }   n \geq 3\text{ odd}, \cr
   SU(2) & \text{for }   n=1
   \end{array} \right.  $$
   i.e. odd-dimensional representations are not [faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithful_representation).
3. It is possible to apply $\rho$ to both sides of OP's eq. (1) without contradictions. Eq. (1) is also discussed in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/394303/2451).

--

$^1$ Define the Lie group $$SU(2)~:=~\{ g \in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid g^{\dagger}\eta g=\eta \wedge \det (g) = 1 \}$$ with a $2\times 2$ positive definite, real metric
$$\eta_{ab}~=~{\rm diag}(+1,+1).$$
The corresponding Lie algebra is the set of traceless anti-hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices
$$su(2)~:=~\{ x \in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid x^{\dagger}=-\eta x\eta^{-1} \wedge {\rm tr} (x) = 0 \}.$$

The group isomorphism $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong SO(3)$ can be explicitly constructed by

- using a bijective isometry
  $$(\mathbb{R}^3, ||\cdot||^2)~\cong~ (su(2),\det(\cdot))$$
  between the 3-dimensional Euclidean space and the Lie algebra $su(2)$ (a traceless anti-hermitian $2\times 2$ matrix has non-negative determinant);
- using the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) ${\rm Ad}: SU(2)\to GL(su(2))\cong GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ given by
  $${\rm Ad} (g)~:=~ gxg^{-1}, \qquad g\in SU(2), \qquad x\in su(2); $$
- identifying
  $$ O(3)~\cong~ O(su(2)).$$

One may show that
$${\rm Im}({\rm Ad})~\cong~ SO(3)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
{\rm ker}({\rm Ad})~=~\{\pm{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\} .$$
An equivalent proof uses quarternions, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/2451) Phys.SE post.