# Parameter space of $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, topology, lie-algebra, group-representations

1. Is it parameter space of $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ are same?
2. can we use quaternions to represent both groups?
3. what about their connectedness?

Comment: What do you mean by "parameter space"?

Comment: Parameter space usually refers to the space of parameters of a physical model, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: parameter space is a manifold every point in that manifold corresponds to a group element

Comment: Lie groups *are* manifolds. I'm not sure I understand the difference between asking whether the "parameter space" of these groups is the same and asking whether the *groups* are the same. The properties of the group manifolds of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ should be easy to find, e.g. on their Wikipedia pages.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399546/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394152/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Robin Raj After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. For more information see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: ok @walber97  i will do it

Answer (score 4):

The group manifold of ${\rm SU}(2)$ is the three sphere $S^3$. The group manifold of ${\rm SO}(3)$ is the three-sphere with antipodal points identified. The two spaces have different connectectness (measured by homotopy) because $\pi_1({\rm SU}(2))= \{0\}$ and $\pi_1({\rm SO}(3)={\mathbb Z}_2$.  ${\rm SU}(2)$ is a double cover of ${\rm SO}(3)$. You can identify ${\rm SU}(2)$ with the group of unit length quaternions by the homomorphism
$$
U= x_0{\mathbb I}-ix_1 \sigma_1-ix_2 \sigma_2-ix_3 \sigma_3 \leftrightarrow {\bf q}=x_0+x_1{\bf i}+x_2{\bf j}+x_3 {\bf k}.
$$
Here $U\in {\rm SU}(2)$ and  ${\bf q}\in {\mathbb H}$ and $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$.  To get ${\rm SO}(3)$ you identify ${\bf q}$ with $-{\bf q}$.