# Why a group that describe rotations always have $su(2)$ Lie algebra?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotation, lie-algebra

I'm reading the book Physics from Symmetry by Jakob Schwichtenberg. In part II the author explain the Lie group theory and in particular he treat the $SU(2)$ group. At a certain point the author tells us that $SU(2)$ is the covering group of the Lie algebra $su(2)$ and this involve that every group with that Lie algebra can be described using $SU(2)$.
After that the author seems to take for granted that every group that describe 3D rotations must have the $su(2)$ Lie algebra and for this reason he study the $SU(2)$ representations.
My question is, why every group that describe 3D rotations must have the $su(2)$ Lie algebra? Is it because $su(2$) Lie algebra encode some sort of behavior of the rotations that we assume to be true?

Comment: How do you use the fact the the lie algebras *so(3)* and *su(2)* are the same?

Comment: Sorry my English Is poor, what do you mean with "how do you use"?

Comment: I  imagine you are asking how the Lie algebra of the rotation group SO(3) which is that of *su(2)* as well motivates the representation theory of the connected component of SU(2)? But you need to add details for clarity.

Comment: yes, I understood that $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ have the same Lie algebra, and that we can write a 2 to 1 map from  $SU(2)$ to SO(3). It looks clear to me that $SU(2)$ is the more complete group with that Lie algebra. It is possible a description of rotations that has another Lia algebra?

Comment: ? In our 3 space dimensions, the *only* Lie algebra of the [Rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)  is *so(3)*. Also [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group). Is this the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Confusion about rotations of quantum states: (3) versus (2)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394152)

Comment: Yes is this the question, how do you know that there isn't another description of the rotations with another Lie algebra? because to me it looks like we have found 2 description of rotations, SU(2) and SO(3), we have seen that they have same Lie algebra and so we have assumed all the descriptions will have that Lie algebra

Comment: You are confused: The rotation group *defines* SO(3), and additional reps are associated projectively to it via its Lie algebra, *so(3) ~ su(2)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments,

> Yes is this the question, how do you know that there isn't another description of the rotations with another Lie algebra? because to me it looks like we have found 2 description of rotations, SU(2) and SO(3), we have seen that they have same Lie algebra and so we have assumed all the descriptions will have that Lie algebra.

I believe there is a fundamental misunderstanding here, so I'll try to quickly review the story.

**I: Representations of SO(3)**

The group $SO(3)$ **is** the rotation group in 3D space.  It is defined by its fundamental representation as the $3\times 3$ real, orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$.  This representation allows us to act on elements of $\mathbb R^3$ with elements of $SO(3)$ via standard matrix multiplication.

From here, it is natural to ask what effect a rotation has on something which *isn't* an element of $\mathbb R^3$.  This leads us to the representation theory of Lie groups.  Given some vector space $V$, we seek a map $\rho: SO(3) \rightarrow GL(V)$ (where $GL(V)$ is the set of invertible linear maps from $V\rightarrow V$) which has the following property:

$$\forall R_1,R_2 \in SO(3), \qquad \rho(R_1\circ R_2)= \rho(R_1)\circ \rho(R_2)$$

Such a map is called a *representation* of $SO(3)$ on the representation space $V$, and for every rotation $R\in SO(3)$, $\rho(R)$ provides the corresponding action on elements of $V$.

---

**II: Representations of $\frak{so}(3)$**

As it turns out, it is quite cumbersome to work directly with representations of groups.  Fortunately, we know that at least in some connected neighborhood of the identity element, we can form a one-to-one correspondence between a Lie group $G$ and its associated Lie algebra $\frak g$, with the elements of $G$ obtained from the elements of $\frak g$ by exponentiation.  Therefore, rather than seeking representations of $SO(3)$ on vector spaces, we seek representations of $\frak{so}(3)$ on them, which we can then (maybe) exponentiate to obtain representations of the original group.

The fundamental representation of $\frak{so}(3)$ is the $3\times 3$ real, antisymmetric matrices.  The standard basis $L_i$, $i=1,2,3$ has commutation relations
$$[L_i,L_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}L_k$$

A representation of the Lie *algebra* $\frak{so}(3)$ on a vector space $V$ is a *linear* map $\varphi:{\frak{so}(3)}\rightarrow {\frak{gl}}(V)$ ( where ${\frak{gl}}(V)$ is the set of linear maps from $V\rightarrow V$) subject to the condition

$$\forall g,h \in {\frak{so}}(3), \qquad \varphi\big([g,h]\big) = \big[\varphi(g),\varphi(h)\big]$$

The linearity makes this much nicer to work with.  We can simply search for sets of three matrices (or operators, in the infinite-dimensional case) which obey the right commutation relations, and this will constitute a representation of $\frak{so}(3)$.

---

**III: Projective Representations and the Universal Cover**

It turns out that a representation of a Lie algebra $\frak g$ does *not* automatically yield a representation of the corresponding Lie group $G$ upon exponentiation if $G$ is not simply-connected (and $SO(3)$ is not).  In this case, we encounter representations of $\frak{so}(3)$ which, when exponentiated, yield [projective representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) of $SO(3)$ instead; that is, we will have that

$$\forall R_1,R_2\in SO(3), \qquad \rho(R_1\circ R_2)=c(R_1,R_2) \rho(R_1)\circ\rho(R_2)$$

where $c(R_1,R_2)$ is some constant. Physically, this is actually desirable in the sense that [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) tells us that we can represent symmetry transformations as unitary operators *up to a phase*.  If we restricted our attention only to properly unitary representations of our symmetry group, then we would miss some.  Unfortunately, projective representations can be a pain to work with because of these extra factors which we would need to keep track of.

This leads us to the concept of the [universal cover](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/lie-groups/lie-groups-and-lie-algebras/the-universal-cover-of-a-lie-group/).  Given a Lie group $G$, its universal cover $U(G)$ is the *unique* simply connected Lie group which shares the same Lie algebra. Since it is simply connected, every representation of $\frak{g}$ gives rise to a genuine, non-projective representation of $U(G)$.  In other words, rather than considering *projective* representations of $SO(3)$, we can consider *genuine* representations of $U\big(SO(3)\big)$.

---

To summarize, our goal was to find representations of $SO(3)$ which can act on vector spaces other than $\mathbb R^3$.  It is much more convenient to consider representations of the Lie algebra $\frak{so}(3)$, but because $SO(3)$ is not simply-connected, some representations of $\frak{so}(3)$ give rise to *projective* representations of $SO(3)$ rather than genuine ones.

In the context of quantum mechanics, this is actually a good thing, but projective representations are annoying to work with.  Because every projective representation of $SO(3)$ is a *genuine* representation of the universal cover $U\big(SO(3)\big) \simeq SU(2)$, we can study the latter without worrying about those pesky factors we'd need to keep track of by studying the former.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, very illuminating!